# Reverse Navigation Menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I have my navigation menu showing up in reverse. I think it is a css problem but I can't find the problem. Please help:
http://www.jamonit.org/dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
#menu-header-nav-1 li {
    float: left;
}

#menu-header-nav-1 {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: That put them in the right order but I want the menu to align to the right.

Comment: you are welcome, so if it help solve the problec could you accept answer pls?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with the site I was building.
What worked for me is to use "text-align" rather than "float" to move the li items to the right.  "Float" changes the order, "text-align" does not.

```
// Div around the #main-menu div that floats the whole list to the right
#menu-wrapper{
     float: right;
}

//Div containing your wp menu UL
#main-menu{
   text-align: right;
}
```